# Deleting user account triggers deletion of another nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Db structure:

```
--followers
  -followedUser1
   -user1
  -followedUser2
   -user1
   -user2
--users
  -user1
   -followed
    -followedUser1
    -followedUser2
  -user2(followedUser1)
   -followed
    -followedUser2
  -user3(followedUser2)
```

Everytime user follows(onCreate) & unfollows(onDelete) under followers/{followedUser}/{followerUser} path, it triggers function which increment or derement count and assigning or detaching posts from follower. It's working via fanout method, and there're no problems. Now, worse part comes when some user deletes account completely together with detaching his followers from himself(because his account will be a ghost), i've set trigger onDelete to indicate whenever it'll happen, then iterating through this user's (i.e.user3) followers removes himself from corresponding followers plus his account, it looks like this then:

```
--followers
  -followedUser1
   -user1
  -followedUser2
   -user1
   -user2
--users
  -user1
   -followed
    -followedUser1
  -user2(followedUser1)
```

Now, problematic part - when promise returns i'd like to also remove whole follower/followedUser2(because it's a ghost now) path but... there is a trigger which unfortunately executes for every follower under(onDelete).  So, is there any chance to remove path above(levelup) deletetion trigger without triggering children itself? Or any other approach would be great, thanks

edit: Dont get me wrong, it'll work but if number of followers under followedUser would be "a lot" server will die after 100... trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, there is no way to filter what deletion events will trigger the function, so you are correct, the function will be triggered once for each user the deleted user was following. I recognize this is one of many use cases where such functionality would be useful, so if you get a chance, please fill out a feature request [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your multiple-update problem can be fixed with a [multi-location updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)

In very quickly hacked together and not tested typescript:

```
export const cleanupFollowers = functions.auth.user().onDelete(event => {
  const user = event.data.userId;
  const followersNode = admin.database().ref(`followers/${user}`);
  const followers = _.keys(await followersNode.once('value'));

  // Every follower also has a reverse node for this user. Get the list of keys:
  const reverseNodesToDelete = followers.map(follower => `followers/${follower}/${user}`);
  // Model this update as a map of deep key -> null to delete all at once
  let cleanup = _.keyBy(reverseNodesToDelete, null);
  // add one more update: deleting full node for the deleted user.
  cleanup[`followers/${user}`] = null;

  // do all deletions as one database request:
  return admin.database().ref().update(cleanup);
 }
```

Note that this will still fire your counting function, but that should be fine to run in parallel. It probably makes your app simpler to have each invariant captured separately.

Comment: Also, for reference, '_' Is the commonly used variable name for the lodash module. It's a really great tool that helps you write functional code to do list-comprehensions. This style of coding lets you write much terser code that doesn't need to worry about off-by-one errors or edge cases with lists of zero, one, and many.

Comment: Thank you, but this is what I got already. I think I might not clarified my question clearly. My case is user have let's say 100000 followers and he wants to delete his account, now my counting and attaching/ detaching post function would fire up 100000 times, so wouldn't it be better if i'll take everything what's connected with that trigger and put it inside multi-location update like you have to make previous trigger deactivated, but that's my question: how to filter that i'm deleting user account with his followers + count them etc and prevent (somehow) unfollows(onDelete) trigger to fire

Comment: I see. This is a different issue than I thought it was. You'll actually run into a different issue at 100K followers. The database has a hard limit at 1K events per write; if you exceed this no events are fired. You can either batch your writes or abuse this to also update the count (but be careful that a transaction across 100K nodes is almost sure to fail). Honestly, 100K updates seems like a bit of an odd edge case for you to spend time optimizing (as long as it works). Do you really expect users to gain such popularity and leave frequently?

Comment: As an additional warning, even Facebook only allows a user or page to follow 5K people (facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=567604083305019). If you expect high connections, you may need to consider optimizations like asymmetric relationships.

Comment: No, I don't think I would need that much connections per one time, but in my currently settings there is possibility some user with any amount followers'd trigger counting x that unfollows number. So, yeah, i'm trying to implement some kind of twitter clone, when you can see user's followers and following persons, and i'm hitting a wall here. In order to provide how many followers/following he has I need count that by db records. I though about setting it up on a client like counting followers on the fly, but this wont work bc i'm batch fetching basically every data.

Comment: In simpler words: i need to know how many followers and followed persons user has, and in case user deletes his account be able somehow decrease his follower's followed number (they followed this user) -1. You can think of this like instagram's Justin Bieber account, what will happen if he'd want to delete his account with 50milions followers attached, how they'll recount under every follower that justin bieber doesn't exist and now this particular's following number would be -1 and remove every bieber's posts from followers? The best solution thought would be to disabled "account deletion"

Comment: exactly the same problem is here https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count where if you want to delete post it would trigger countings multiple times, bc under post's path triggers are set. If f.e. google functions will have some kind of deletion filter, whenever parent path is deleted, triggers under this one should not be fired up would be a solution to this topic